# cant generate list using batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to get a list of all parent directorys on my pc using the following but it doesn't work?

```
for %%p in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do if exist for dir %%p:\nul /ad /b > C:\directorylist.txt
```

could someone help?

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: well I addes a pause to see what the CMD would return and I get the following: C:\>if exist dir a:\ /ad /b 1>directorylist.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had some errors.  The \nul is no longer correct in all cases in NT versions of Windows.

```
@echo off
for %%p in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do if exist  %%p:\ dir /ad /b >> C:\directorylist.txt
```

Comment: that (though I wasnt aware of the Nul situation) didnt help my CMD keeps returning 1>directorylist.txt when iI would expect somthing like  FOLDERNAME>Directorylist.txt ?

Comment: The `1>` is normal.  What do you get in the file?  You did copy and paste the changed code, didn't you?

Comment: yes i copy and pasted it no file generated but Im just about to restart my pc... I have noticed in the past that bat files sometimes get stuck into memorie and run as if not eddited. BRB with the answer :)

Comment: aahnow it works just a pc hick-up I guess, thanks

Comment: ok.  take note that c:\ is not writable in modern Windows due to access restrictions.  Try creating the file on your desktop with this: `>>"%USERPROFILE%\desktop\directorylist.txt"`